# Where can I get parts lists from sets by numbered bag?

Tags: piece-information, instructions

I have a hodge podge of LEGO pieces that I am trying to organize into sets. I have most of the boxes so it hasn’t been too difficult, just time consuming. Anyway, I’m currently working on set 75093. Bags 1, 2, 4, and 5 are open. Bags 3 and 6 are still sealed. I’d like to not open them, if possible. Problem is I can’t see all the parts in the bags and I’d like a list of parts by bag number. Is there such a thing? My concern is I may be duplicating/using pieces that might belong to other sets trying to complete this set.

Answer (score 5):

I'm afraid there's no registry keeping records of elements included in each numbered part.

[Instructions for 75093 set](https://www.lego.com/cdn/product-assets/product.bi.core.pdf/6131100.pdf) show which parts of a set could be assembled from each numbered bag, including parts for each step. You can then collect elements listed under each step to combine into numbered bags of your own. Getting all extra pieces might be a little hard, since you cannot check what is included in sealed bags. However you can guess which ones should have been included in opened bags. You can check which Extra parts come at the bottom on Bricklink's [page for 75093 set](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=75093-1).

Comment: peeron.com used to maintain bag information, but hasn't been updated in a long time.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I considered what you are saying, but here’s my question: I’ve noticed that not all parts to a particular module are contained in the corresponding bag for that module and I’ve found that some left over parts often go to another module. That being the case, I was really hoping there was a database somewhere that listed parts by bag number. Oh well, I guess I’ll have to open the remaining bags to know for sure I have a complete “set.” I’m not worried about the few extras that Lego throws in. Thanks again for your response!

Comment: @Tiger37229 perhaps you mean that some left over elements (say from bag #1) that you've used further in the build were Extra parts from that bag. You would still end up with the same Extra elements in the end.

Comment: My experience backs up @Alex - I am confident I've never had, say, a part from bag 1 which was not used in the bag 1 section but was needed in, say, the bag 2 section, because there weren't enough in bag 2. This would have messed up the ability to split a big set into multiple concurrent builds by multiple groups of children when a birthday party got rained out so a big Jurassic World set got opened for everyone to build (to pick an example which happened to us in the Before Times).

Comment: It’s possible that leftover parts were just extra parts that often come with Lego sets, and it’s possible that in the act of assembling a set it just appeared as though left over parts from say bag 1 were needed in a subsequent module, but I’m trying not to open unopened bags or use parts from other sets to complete this particular set leaving me short with those sets. It appears I’m just going to have to bite the bullet and open the remaining bags. Thanks for the responses. 